# "Lazy" MVC5 Razor execution - ASP.NET (optimization)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor

We wrote razor extension method to use it in vbhtml view which make translations of static, non list, non generated elements i.e. titles, static navigation elements and so on :

```
<h1>@Html.GetTagText("aaa"(real string), cultureCode, translationContext)</h1>
```

with this idea we generate X calls to DB, every time we call this method.

Question : Is there any Event raised by Razor Engine before transform and After transform, or somekind of entrypoint in ASP.NET page lifecycle (pre render, post render) which will allow us to :

1. Collect all getTagText calls to list
2. do rest of razor work
3. give back all translations in one DB shoot
4. put/replace correct translations into correct places

or maybe i am thinking totaly wrong, and razor isn't good place to do that kind of "magic" ? I need generic idea, something that i will write once, to do not reproduce this in every controller.

Comment: Side note: it is generally bad idea to make slow I/O bound synchronous calls from the view... and you can't make async calls from view till ASP.NET MVC6 (2016) - see info on [MVC6 - view components](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/vc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you handle this kind of work in your controller. Create a view model where you can place your translated text for the fields you need translated and populate the view model in the controller.

I do not think there are any events raised by an MVC view. I have tried to hook into these kinds of events to measure the page rendering time and could not find any such hooks.

Comment: Okay, @steve Mallory, so would you mind to be more specific - In your approach, i should write somekind of master controller, and derive all controllers from this parrent TranslationController, and parse the views like string ?

Comment: @Lightning3 Well, that's a matter of style, but I would say that if every controller will do translation, then it makes sense to write a base controller to handle that work. That said, I would probably write a helper class, very much like your `GetTagText()` method, and use that class in my controllers.